# Google Tag Manager Variables - Extract Price Based on Field Label

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I believe the value of the classes in my use-case rotate or change which has caused my current approach to not work.

**Current Approach Below:**

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul.sc-kUVfrs.cDZGmz li.sc-kbQyxg span.sc-kYxDKI.sc-iiUMNf.YHzWW.cmsXMM');
```

I'm interested in understanding how I can parse a value given text from it's header. In the example below, we have the last value in a list that is labeled "Estimated Total Cost" and it's corresponding value "$1,377.00".

Is it possible in GTM to write a custom javascript variable that returns our value of "$1,377.00" based on looking for the value "Estimated Total Cost"?

```
<li class="sc-iyNfIN kzTAaw"><span class="sc-kYxDKI odYTF">Estimated Total Cost: </span><span class="sc-kYxDKI sc-HkLeE YHzWW iIlOcP">$1,377.00</span></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the front end code to add datalayer.push() commands, then you can select elements based on the structure of the DOM.

You could create a Custom Javascript Variable to access your element, for example:

```
function findElementText() {
    var lastLi = document.querySelector('ul li:last-child');
    var secondSpan = lastLi.querySelector('span:nth-child(2)');
    var textSecondSpan = secondSpan.textContent;
return textSecondSpan;
}
```

Note that this approach is fragile and makes your tracking dependent on the page structure around the list element.

If you want to search for that specific text you could try to add an HTML script tag with the following code that pushes the price to the data layer:

```
<script>
function getPrice() {
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    var firstSpan = lis[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
    var secondSpan = lis[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[1];
    if (firstSpan.textContent.trim() === 'Estimated Total Cost:') {
        return dataLayer.push({'event':'eventName','price': secondSpan.textContent});
    }
  }
}
getPrice();
</script>
```

Comment: Agreed the best solution is a dataLayer push. For now though, the above does not return the expected value "$1,377.00". Separately, is it possible to base it on finding the string "Estimated Total Cost" rather than the position based approach looking for the last list element? Appreciate your time and thoughts on this.

Comment: I didn't manage to search for the text using a custom Javascript variable, however I tried pushing the price to the data layer by inserting some Javascript in a custom HTML tag. Maybe that could be a solution? Edited my answer to include the custom HTML script and a new attempt at the DOM selection also.